# Angular directive not rendered in IE11 but in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am trying to use a custom directive in a module. It works in chrome but noch in IE 11 or lower.

**Module controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
        function ($scope,  $stateParams) {
            'use strict';

            $scope.config = {
                entityId: $stateParams.entityid

            }
        }]);
```

**Module html**

```
<div data-my-directive data-config="config" />
```

**Directive JS**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', ['$state',
        function ($state) {
            'use strict';

            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: "template.html",
                scope: {
                    config: "=config"
                },
                link: function ($scope) {
                    'use strict';
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

**Directive HTML**
    Hello World

The "Hello World" is never rendered and the link function is never called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seeing your main app file would be helpful.

Comment: angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ngSanitize']);

Comment: no config? no run? Please post the whole thing into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you did a straight copy/paste, your problem is here:

```
templateUrl: "template.html"),
```

and here:

```
});
```

You've got stray closing parenthesis. Remove them. Chrome is more forgiving than IE in some cases.

Comment: sry this is just a little copy/paste error when creating this post. (the real path is created by calling a method)

Comment: it was a bug inside this function. Thanks for this. The evil method was "str.endsWith()" which is not supported in IE